# calling 2 times a php function that removes mongo documents

Tags: php, mongodb

I've problems when I call 2 or more times to a function that removes documents from mongo.

Here is the function:

```
function deleteUser($userId){
    $rangeQuery = array('metadata.userId' => intval($userId));
    $cursor = $this->collection->remove($rangeQuery);
}
```

Function works fine if I only call once. The problem is when I call the function several times. For example:

```
deleteUser(2);
deleteUser(3);
deleteUser(4);
```

This code only delete the first user (UserId = 2). User 3 or 4 are not removed. I need to reload the page to delete 3, and another reload to delete 4. There is any limit for removing documents in mongo?

This is the log using php mongolog class:

```
Message: CON INFO: mongo_get_read_write_connection: finding a STANDALONE connection
Message: CON FINE: found connection 81.4
Message: CON FINE: is_ping: pinging 81.4
Message: CON FINE: send_packet: read from header: 36
Message: CON FINE: send_packet: data_size: 17
Message: CON WARN: is_ping: last pinged at 1383224885; time: 11701ms
Message: REPLSET FINE: finding candidate servers
Message: REPLSET FINE: - all servers
Message: REPLSET FINE: filter_connections: adding connections:
Message: REPLSET FINE: - connection: type: STANDALONE, socket: 1600, ping: 11701, hash: 81.4
Message: REPLSET FINE: filter_connections: done
Message: REPLSET FINE: limiting by seeded/discovered servers
Message: REPLSET FINE: - connection: type: STANDALONE, socket: 1600, ping: 11701, hash: 81.4
Message: REPLSET FINE: limiting by seeded/discovered servers: done
Message: REPLSET FINE: sorting servers by priority and ping time
Message: REPLSET FINE: - connection: type: STANDALONE, socket: 1600, ping: 11701, hash: 81.4
Message: REPLSET FINE: sorting servers: done
Message: REPLSET FINE: selecting near servers
Message: REPLSET FINE: selecting near servers: nearest is 11701ms
Message: REPLSET FINE: - connection: type: STANDALONE, socket: 1600, ping: 11701, hash: 81.4
Message: REPLSET FINE: selecting near server: done
Message: REPLSET FINE: pick server: random element 0
Message: REPLSET INFO: - connection: type: STANDALONE, socket: 1600, ping: 11701, hash: 81.4
Message: IO FINE: is_gle_op: no
Message: CON FINE: The requested database (readings) is not what we have in the link info (admin)
Message: CON FINE: The link info has 'admin' as database, no need to clone it then
Message: CON INFO: mongo_get_read_write_connection: finding a STANDALONE connection
Message: CON FINE: found connection 81.4 (looking for 81.4)
Message: CON FINE: is_ping: pinging 81.4
Message: CON FINE: is_ping: skipping: last ran at 1383224885, now: 1383224885, time left: 5
Message: REPLSET FINE: finding candidate servers
Message: REPLSET FINE: - all servers
Message: REPLSET FINE: filter_connections: adding connections:
Message: REPLSET FINE: - connection: type: STANDALONE, socket: 1600, ping: 11701, hash: 81.4
Message: REPLSET FINE: filter_connections: done
Message: REPLSET FINE: limiting by seeded/discovered servers
Message: REPLSET FINE: - connection: type: STANDALONE, socket: 1600, ping: 11701, hash: 81.4
Message: REPLSET FINE: limiting by seeded/discovered servers: done
Message: REPLSET FINE: sorting servers by priority and ping time
Message: REPLSET FINE: - connection: type: STANDALONE, socket: 1600, ping: 11701, hash: 81.4
Message: REPLSET FINE: sorting servers: done
Message: REPLSET FINE: selecting near servers
Message: REPLSET FINE: selecting near servers: nearest is 11701ms
Message: REPLSET FINE: - connection: type: STANDALONE, socket: 1600, ping: 11701, hash: 81.4
Message: REPLSET FINE: selecting near server: done
Message: REPLSET FINE: pick server: random element 0
Message: REPLSET INFO: - connection: type: STANDALONE, socket: 1600, ping: 11701, hash: 81.4
Message: IO FINE: is_gle_op: no
```

thank you!

Comment: No there is no limit I am unsure what the problem is but I don't think it is mongo

Comment: thank you Sammaye for your answer

Comment: Are you sure all your user ids are actually stored as numbers?

Comment: yes, I'm very sure. I added intval to assure that I pass an Integer to mongo. Mongo is very sensitive with that.

Comment: Honestly the only thing I can think of that the data types dont match

Comment: This MongoLog output looks fake. The hash, connection, and socket values there are bogus, and you have *extremely* latency on the connection. Furthermore, it does not look like the full output as it shows only two operations, but your code says 3

Comment: Please make sure you post your _exact_ code you are using. No pseudo code or "almost like this". It needs to be your _exact_ code because you have a problem in your code

Comment: Actually, it almost makes sense. Because of the extreme latency on your connection, it does take 3-4 seconds for you application to see that all these users have been removed. If you switch over to use WriteConcerns then you'r application will see the changes right away: http://us2.php.net/mongo.writeconcerns

Comment: Hi bjori, it make sense the latency problem. Now I'm running the code in the same server of the mongodb and is running ok! I was running the code in localhost. Thank you!!

Comment: Am also facing the same issue. I think it's an issue with the PHP-Mongo driver version. I have the same script running on another server without any problem. Please update if you found solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function deleteUser($userId){
    $rangeQuery = array('metadata.userId' => userId);
    $cursor = $this->collection->remove($rangeQuery);
}
```

You are missing the $ sign before your userId variable.

it should be:

```
$rangeQuery = array('metadata.userId' => $userId);
```

I recommend you turn on PHP error logging to catch this sort of errors :)

Comment: Thank you bjori!! I have done a wrong paste of my code. I've the '$'. there is also an intval to be sure that is a integer and not a string.

Comment: Now the problem is still there. The function runs perfectly if I only call one time. If I call 2 times or more, mongo only delete the first user. I'm running now with the PHP log and no errors are displayed. is very strange

Comment: Maybe you should post the *actual* code you are using then, it is impossible to debug code based on "maybe it looks like this, and called like this"

Comment: thank you Bjori. I've modified the question with the actual code (your observation of the '$' and the intval that I've added)

Comment: Could you var_dump() the $cursor please and post what you get from that? If that doesn't give anything useful, try enabling driver logging: php.net/mongolog.setcallback

Comment: The response of var_dump() is boolean true. Mongolog appears very normal. I answer my question to show you